# Why is my RouteTable.Routes property an instance of System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection and not of System.Web.Http.HttpRouteCollection?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to get ASP.NET MVC Web API working in my Web Forms solution.  And no, I unfortunately can't just switch everything to MVC.  Right now I am stuck on mapping my HttpRoute.  I'm currently trying to add my route to the `Application_Start` method in `Global.asax` but having trouble.

All of the instructions I've found state that I need to call `RouteTable.Routes`' `MapHttpRoute`method.  BUT - this is a method that exists only on the class `System.Web.Http.HttpRouteCollection`.  For some reason, though - my `RouteTable.Routes` instance is of the type `System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection`.

Anyone know how I can make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know what the problem was, but I ended up just calling the MapHttpRoute extension method directly off of the RouteCollectionExtensions object and that worked fine.  Oy.